# PHP explode String with Data Pairs

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a dataset and I want to conevert it into an array and I just can't figure out how... 
I've tried a couple things like preg_replace() with regex and explode() but it doesn't come out the way I need it.

So my dataset looks like this:

```
dataCrossID=12345, DeviceID=[ID=1234567]
dataCrossID=5678, DeviceID=[ID=7654321]
dataCrossID=67899, DeviceID=[ID=87654321]
```

and the Array should look like this:

```
$dataSet(
          [12345] => 1234567,
          [5678]  => 7654321,
          [67899] => 87654321,
         )
```

I tried regex but the fact that the numbers got different lenghts makes it hard for me.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is the tool you need.

Comment: Show your code and I'll show you mine :-)

Comment: @axiac that was definitly the function I was looking for! you saved my day! cheers mate :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to identify the pieces of text you need:

```
$input = <<< E
dataCrossID=12345, DeviceID=[ID=1234567]
dataCrossID=5678, DeviceID=[ID=7654321]
dataCrossID=67899, DeviceID=[ID=87654321]
E;

preg_match_all('/dataCrossID=(\d+), DeviceID=\[ID=(\d+)\]/', $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

The content of `$matches` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => dataCrossID=12345, DeviceID=[ID=1234567]
            [1] => 12345
            [2] => 1234567
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => dataCrossID=5678, DeviceID=[ID=7654321]
            [1] => 5678
            [2] => 7654321
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => dataCrossID=67899, DeviceID=[ID=87654321]
            [1] => 67899
            [2] => 87654321
        )
)
```

You can now iterate over `$matches` and use the values at positions `1` and `2` as keys and values to extract the data into the desired array:

```
$output = array_reduce(
    $matches,
    function(array $c, array $m) {
        $c[$m[1]] = $m[2];
        return $c;
    },
    array()
);
print_r($output);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [12345] => 1234567
    [5678] => 7654321
    [67899] => 87654321
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be using `preg_match_all` with an simple regular expression.

```
$data = 'dataCrossID=12345, DeviceID=[ID=1234567]
dataCrossID=5678, DeviceID=[ID=7654321]
dataCrossID=67899, DeviceID=[ID=87654321]';

preg_match_all('/=([0-9]+).*=([0-9]+)/', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$dataSet = [];
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $dataSet[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}

print_r($dataSet);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks to @axiac I got the function I was looking for but i gotta thank you for the regex, way better than the ones i created :D cheers mate!